# Overriding Methods with the subtype

Tags: java, overriding

I learnt that I can override a method if it has the same signature.

However the return type of overridden method in the derived class can be the sub-typed of super class method return type. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code if the statement provided above is correct?

```
class Base{
    public int getValue(){ return 222; } //1
}

class Sub extends Base{
    public byte getValue(){ return 10; } //2
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Base b = new Sub();
        System.out.println(b.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to override, doesn't the method need to have the **exact** same signature as the method its overriding?

Comment: byte is not a subtype of int, they are not related by inheritance as they are primitives. @Anthony, the methods indeed have the same signature.

Comment: The return type is not part of a method signature in Java.

Comment: @ant it can be covariant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`byte` is a primitive type, not a sub-type of `int`. However,

```
static class Super {
    public Date getValue() {
        return new Date();
    } // 1
}

static class Sub extends Super {
    public Timestamp getValue() {
        return new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    } // 2

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Super b = new Sub();
    System.out.println(b.getValue());
}
```

Will work because `java.sql.Timestamp` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`